# How to change options in the fcolorbox environment

Tags: boxes, framed, colorbox

How can I change the options in `\fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}{My text}` so that the box gets rounded corners for instance or a thicker border?

Best regards

Henrik

Comment: `\fcolorbox` uses `\rules` which are either vertical or horizontal, but not rounded. You can change the `\fboxrule` width however.

Answer (score 14):

`\fcolorbox` falls back to `\colorbox`, which can't have rounded corners by itself (it would be possible to redefine it and use some `\put` statements to change the joints of the rules, however)

The width of the frame is defined by `\fboxrule`, so changing the width will provide other boxes in this sense.
Another length is `\fboxsep`, which is the distance between the border and the box content -- it can be changed as well, but the distance is the same for all four boundaries!

For the box corners I suggest `tcolorbox` which is very configurable, see the almost easiest usage of the `tcolorbox` environment in the code. The options `leftrule`, `rightrule`, `toprule` and `bottomrule` allow individual widths for the relevant frame rules, which is not possible for `\fcolorbox` (again, without redefining `\fcolorbox`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}{My text}

{%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{5pt}
\fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}{My text}
}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!30,%gray background
                  colframe=black,% black frame colour
                  width=5cm,% Use 5cm total width,
                  arc=3mm, auto outer arc,
                 ]
  My text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,
                  colback=gray!30,%gray background
                  colframe=Maroon,% black frame colour
                  width=5cm,% Use 5cm total width,
                  arc=3mm, auto outer arc,
                  boxrule=5pt,
                  drop shadow={Maroon!50!gray!80}
                 ]
  My text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]